# How to apply SRP principle in C when I cannot access functions or variables outside of my module?

Tags: c, sdl

I am trying to learn to apply the Single Responsibility Principle to C but I am running into a problem where my "module/file" does not have access to the functions and variables I need.

For example, I am creating this event-driven game that polls for keyboard events and then does something. I want to extract it into it's own file but then I do not have access to any of the functions and variables that I need.

Maybe my architecture is flawed here and I'm doing it wrong. What is the best practice here?

I would like to refactor this code. Here inside of `main()` is the main loop that polls for keyboard input and then depending on which key was pressed, it changes variables and calls methods that are defined in `main.c` like `quit=1` or `placeShip()`.

But according to SRP, each module should be responsible for only 1 thing. So, I would like to put the input processing in it's own file. But then I won't have access to any of the functions/variables that are in `main.c` - since that is where the main game logic lives.

**main.c**

```c
int main() {
    // ...

    int quit = 0;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED, & window, & renderer);

    while (!quit) {
      while (SDL_PollEvent( & event) == 1) {
        switch (event.type) {
          case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = 1;
            break;

          case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
              case SDLK_RETURN:
                if (!isShooting) {
                  placeShip(playerShips);
                }
                break;

              case SDLK_SPACE:
                if (!isShooting) {
                  rotateShip(playerShips);
                }

                if (isShooting) {
                  shootAtOpponent(renderer, opponentShips, playerShips);
                }

                break;

              case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                quit = 1;
                break;

              case SDLK_w:
              case SDLK_UP:
                if (!isShooting) {
                  if (playerShips[placingShipIndex].rect.y != gridOffsetY) {
                    playerShips[placingShipIndex].rect.y = playerShips[placingShipIndex].rect.y - cellSize;
                  }
                }

// more code...
```

I would love to refactor this into something like this:

**main.c**

```
include "input.h"

int main()
{
  // ..
  process_input();
  render();
}
```

**input.c** ERRORS eveywhere.... :(

```
int process_input()
{
  // ERROR: I do not have access to quit inside this file
    while (!quit) {
      while (SDL_PollEvent( & event) == 1) {
        switch (event.type) {
          case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = 1; // ERROR: I do not have access to quit inside this file
            break;

          case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
              case SDLK_RETURN:
                if (!isShooting) { // ERROR: I do not have access to isShooting inside this file
                  placeShip(playerShips); // ERROR: I do not have access to placeShip inside this file
                } // ERROR: I do not have access to playerShips inside this file
                break;

}
```

Comment: SRP is an OOP principle and therefore makes sense when the code is object oriented.

Comment: Also, even if we forget about that for a second, function `process_input` hardly complies with the principle, as it has a dozen of "reasons to change". An example of a better design would be a module that delegates event handling to different submodules. This way it's only responsible for mapping the SDL events to the handlers you write.

Comment: That sounds better, how do you implement such a module?

Answer (score 2):

The refactoring you propose, has the problem that process_input has a while loop that does not exit until the game is over, so you get to call render(), only when you exit. One possibility is to use your main loop just to pull events, and do all the processing inside another module:

```
include "logic.h"

static bool ProcessQuit(event)
{
   //Verify if must quit and return boolean
}

int main()
{
  // ...
  while (!quit) 
  {
     if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) == 1) 
     {
        logic_Process(event.type);

        quit = ProcessQuit(event);
     }
}
```

Then, under the logic module you can have other functions to assist the processing, or even create additional modules called by logic.c. For example, you can create a render.c module, called from logic.c
as for encapsulation, you may declare static variables on each module so that they are only seen from the module itself.

The architecture would be something like this:
main (pool events, quit game)
logic (everything else)
render (show the results on screen)

Another option will be to have logic and render at the same level (call both from main) but then, you need to figure out how to pass data from logic to render. That would depend on how much data you need to pass. If there is plenty, you may create a structure variable on main (Context), and pass a reference to both logic and render, on each call.

```
#include "logic.h"
#include "render.h"

typedef struct
{
  //your information
} Context_t;

static Context_t Context = {//initialization};

static bool ProcessQuit(event)
{
   //Verify if must quit and return boolean
}

int main()
{
  // ...
  while (!quit) 
  {
     if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) == 1) 
     {
        logic_Process(&Context, event.type);
        render_Process(&Context);

        quit = ProcessQuit(event);
     }
}
```

Good luck!